# superimpose graphs into one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

i want to combine two graphs int one graphs :
when i try the code bellow :

```
data_df <- df%>%
   filter(!is.na(LayerName)) %>%
   dplyr::select(LayerName, A,B) %>%
   group_by(LayerName) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(lower=min(A),upper=max(A),Mean=mean(A),
                lower_out=min(B),upper_out=max(B),Mean_out=mean(B)) 

  c<-ggplot(data = data_df, mapping = aes(x = LayerName, y = Mean)) +
   geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),color = "red")


   r<-c+ggplot(data = data_df, mapping = aes(x = LayerName, y = Mean_out)) +
   geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = lower_out, ymax = upper_out),color = "blue")+
   theme_bw()
   ggplotly(r)
```

## i get this message error :

```
Don't know how to add ggplot(data = data_df, mapping = aes(x = LayerName, y = Mean_out)) to a plot
```

Comment: Do you mean "superimpose" ?

Comment: Maybe it is better to reshape from wide-to-long and use facets.

Comment: what i mean is to make those two graphes into one graph( i'de be able to see variation of variable A and B in the same graph)

Comment: yes that's what i mean " to superimpose"

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra layers but you want to avoid using `ggplot()` twice. So changing your assignment of r like so would probably work:

```
   r<-c +
   geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(y = Mean_out, ymin = lower_out, ymax = upper_out), color = "blue") +
   theme_bw()
```

Comment: emmm...it doesn't plot the thing i want : when i did this :                                    r<-c+ggplot(data = data_df, mapping = aes(x = LayerName, y = Mean_out))                        it supposed to take Mean_out not the previous Mean on firts lines so it's not correct for me

Comment: @SaraStone You defined `c` as `ggplot(...)` already. As what efbbrown pointed out in his answer, you can add additional `geom_*` layers to it, not another `ggplot(...)`. & by the way, naming a R object `c` is generally not recommended, since it's already a function in the base package.